# Best strategy to use rest web services behind VPN

Tags: java, android, rest, security, vpn

I have an android app that would use certain restful service end point. Right now, the restful service is running on tomcat server and server machine is reachable after connecting to VPN. 
My question is that 
1. How to put the service machine so that it should be protected behind VPN and still, my app would be able to hit the service and get the result. The app is not having any coding related to connection through VPN. and the client is also not willing to remove VPN. So, how through PUBLIC IP or domain, I can plan to use the service in Android app.

I am not a android developer.

Thanks

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could create a second webapp running somewhere in the cloud (e.g. AWS) which knows how to connect to a VPN.  Then, it would just expose its own endpoints which would be directly accessible to an Android phone with an internet connection.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for looking. Its came in my mind but client is not willing too. However, can I setup a Apache server in front of Tomcat and forward all to the tomcat server?

Comment: What is that going to accomplish?  The Apache server would still be behind the VPN, right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisenNo, Apache server will be kept in local network on public ip and will always be connected to VPN.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I found this idea on this forum. So, is that not a good idea?

Comment: I don't know enough about your problem to comment further.  I gave you an upvote, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank U.

Comment: Why would he not allow your server component to create the VPN and expose required functionality outside the VPN, but allow Apache to expose the whole of the API? If he is not willing to expose any of the API, then it can't be solved. Your Android app can't make the VPN connection, because secrets would then be stored in the app, clearly insecure. As probably the most secure option, you need a server, which exposes certain functionality of the original API, in a way that's acceptable for the API owner. So basically what @TimBiegeleisen said.

Comment: @GaborLengyel Thank u for looking. He insists bcz of security. The service is used internlly but there is this app that is using some of the endpoint. This app is already built. This app would be used by few without going to store. My idea of creating of webapp was turned down because of the development cost etc. However, I got Apache -> Tomcat after going through this forum only. Hope this will clear.

Comment: @GaborLengyel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698974/how-to-access-a-web-service-behind-a-nat

Comment: @GaborLengyel They will not allow even partial to expose to another machine.

Comment: The question you linked is very different and is about NAT, not a VPN. Also the clients in the accepted answer are kiosks, not mobile apps. If the API can't be exposed in any way, not even partially through a different component, I'm pretty sure you can't use it from a mobile app unless the app (or the user's phone) itself acts as the VPN client, but that really would be insecure, much more so than allowing controlled partial access externally.