# Can a REST API built with Flask and Python be accessed from an external network?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use a REST API, built using Flask and Python, to create a server from my Raspberry Pi and access it from my iPhone. I have a very simple question: can I access the server from a network other than the one it is created on? So, for example, if the server is created on my home wifi, can I access it from my workplace wifi? If so, how?

Currently, I can access the server from any device connected to the same network. I have seen many similar posts online about similar problems, but I cannot find a direct answer to my question above.

Here is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test")
def hello():
    return jsonify({"about":"Hello World"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=2000,debug=True)
```

If I go onto Safari on my iPhone when connected to mobile data and type in "http://RaspberryPiIP:2000/test", then the page will not load and "take too long to respond." However, if I do the same thing on my home wifi, which the raspberry pi is also connected to, the page will load as expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about networking infrastructure, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your code. You just need to route the requests from your external (public) IP address to the internal IP address of the server in your network. If you are at home, you need to configurate your router. This is often called [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) or port mapping.
You may also want to use a dynamic dns service, because most external ips will be changed frequently by your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access some thing on the internet you need static IP address which will not change like dynamic IPs that your ISP assigns to you. However there are services like [this](https://www.securepoint.de/en/products/nextgen-utm-firewalls/securepoint-dyndns.html) that will provide you with dns name pointed to your dynamic IP address also you need to do some port forwarding which is not safe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You say that this method isn't safe. Is there an alternative you would suggest?

Comment: It is not safe because you are exposing open port to world wide. you can use VPN, check following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698974/how-to-access-a-web-service-behind-a-nat

Comment: "Safe" is relative, if you provide proper authentication and authorization and only expose a defined API to the internet then it is "safe". Just keep in mind that EVERYONE (if he knows your IP) can access your server just as you do if it is connected directly to the internet.

Comment: exactly like you said safe is relative and if you are not familiar with security issues it would leads to disaster.